# Position Vector of a point given three other points

Tags: geometry, vectors

Given a $\Delta ABC$ and a point $P$ such that $AB=a, BC=b, CA=c$ and $PA=\overrightarrow{A}, PB=\overrightarrow{B}, PC=\overrightarrow{C}$, then it's true that $$\vec P=x\vec A+ y\vec B+ z \vec C$$ for $$x+y+z=1$$.

***Now, we can show that: $x=\frac{\text {Area}[PBC]}{\text{Area}[ABC]}$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$. (Take signed area or take $P$ inside $\Delta ABC$ for convenience.***
Don't set values for any of the provided points and consider the origin as $O$ different from any of the above points.

How to show this (the **bold** portion)? One way is to brute force it by considering every length from $O$ and do it. I think that's a way but it might not be a good solution, I presume. Is there any other way using the section formula  $\bigg($ $\vec K= t\vec A + (1-t)\vec B$ (for $A,K,B$ collinear) $\bigg)$? Or any other way that's short and precise?

[image]

Comment: There is something not clear to me what you mean with $PA=\overrightarrow{A}, PB=\overrightarrow{B}, PC=\overrightarrow{C}$, it seems by this that P is set as the origin.

Comment: Actually I did not understand everything clearly. I'm posting a picture above, kindly check and try to understand from the picture. And then, explain it. Thanks

Comment: Kindly explain it. I'm trying to learn Barycentric coordinates but this vectors are quite confusing me. I'm not accustomed to vectors and didn't get any good note/PDF to learn from

Comment: It can be shown by easy geometrical consideration on triangles, I try to find something for you.

Comment: @gimusi I couldn't do it. Can you please elaborate? Also tell if P is the origin here or O? Consider the picture, not my write-up.

Comment: you can set as solved if you are ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proof you can use cross product showing that assuming $\overrightarrow{P}$ as a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{A}$, $\overrightarrow{B}$, $\overrightarrow{C}$:

$$\overrightarrow{P}=\alpha\overrightarrow{A}+\beta\overrightarrow{B}+\gamma \overrightarrow{C}$$ with $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$$

$$\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$$

then, considering signed areas, it can be shown that:

$[ABC]=\frac12 \vec{AB}\times \vec{AC} =\frac12 \vec{A} \times \vec{B}+\frac12 \vec{B} \times \vec{C}+\frac12 \vec{C} \times \vec{A}$

$[PBC]=\frac12 \vec{PB}\times \vec{PC} =\alpha(\frac12 \vec{A} \times \vec{B}+\frac12 \vec{B} \times \vec{C}+\frac12 \vec{C} \times \vec{A}) = \alpha [ABC]$

and similarly:

$[PAC]=\beta [ABC]$

$[PAB]=\gamma [ABC]$

observe that

$[PBC]+[PAC]+[PAB]=\alpha [ABC]+\beta [ABC]+\gamma [ABC]=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)[ABC]=[ABC]$

**NOTE**

Every "point" (i.e. vector) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be expressed by a linear combination of three distinct"points" (i.e. vectors).

Thus, in general, the combination:
$$\overrightarrow{P}=\alpha\overrightarrow{A}+\beta\overrightarrow{B}+\gamma \overrightarrow{C}$$

will lead to a point away from the plane passing through A,B,C.

Assuming:

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$$

we are selecting a particular subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$ that is just **the plane passing through A,B,C**.

Infact:

1. this subspace is a plane since it has 2 dimension (i.e. only 2 parameters can fixed among $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$);
2. it passes through A,B, and C ($P \equiv A$ when $\alpha=1$ and so on).

Linear Algebra guarantees that the definition is well posed as **every point P** on the plane can be selected by an **unique triple** of real numers.

What has been shown is that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ have a precise geometric meaning as areal ratio.

Comment: How does this show that $\alpha \vec {A} + \beta \vec {B} + \gamma \vec {C}$ gives $\vec P$? Or was it a hint?

Comment: I've added some final note to explain betterthe context.

Comment: Okay I somewhat get it